# Don't understand how Python calls this C function

Tags: python, c, function, arguments, swig

please be patient , I am just trying to learn Python, but trying to figure out how some software works ( https://github.com/LBC-LNBio/pyKVFinder/tree/master ) .

Here in https://github.com/LBC-LNBio/pyKVFinder/blob/master/pyKVFinder/grid.py#L960 , `grid.py`I have :

```
 ncav, cavities = _detect(
            nvoxels,
            nx,
            ny,
            nz,
            xyzr,
            P1,
            sincos,
            step,
            probe_in,
            probe_out,
            removal_distance,
            volume_cutoff,
            box_adjustment,
            P2,
            surface,
            nthreads,
            verbose,
        )
```

but `_detect` comes from the C compiled library (  `from _pyKVFinder import _detect, _detect_ladj` , I believe) and in its source code : https://github.com/LBC-LNBio/pyKVFinder/blob/master/C/pyKVFinder.c#L989C1-L994C2 , `pyKVFinder.c`

```
/* Cavity detection */

/*
 * Function: _detect
 * -----------------
 *
 * Detect and cluster cavities
 *
 * PI: 3D grid
 * size: number of voxels in 3D grid
 * nx: x grid units
 * ny: y grid units
 * nz: z grid units
 * atoms: xyz coordinates and radii of input pdb
 * natoms: number of atoms
 * xyzr: number of data per atom (4: xyzr)
 * reference: xyz coordinates of 3D grid origin
 * ndims: number of coordinates (3: xyz)
 * sincos: sin and cos of 3D grid angles
 * nvalues: number of sin and cos (sina, cosa, sinb, cosb)
 * step: 3D grid spacing (A)
 * probe_in: Probe In size (A)
 * probe_out: Probe Out size (A)
 * removal_distance: Length to be removed from the cavity-bulk frontier (A)
 * volume_cutoff: Cavities volume filter (A3)
 * box_adjustment: Box adjustment mode
 * P2: xyz coordinates of x-axis vertice
 * nndims: number of coordinates (3: xyz)
 * is_ses: surface mode (1: SES or 0: SAS)
 * nthreads: number of threads for OpenMP
 * verbose: print extra information to standard output
 *
 * returns: PI[size] (cavities 3D grid) and ncav (number of cavities)
 */

int _detect(int *PI, int size, int nx, int ny, int nz, double *atoms,
            int natoms, int xyzr, double *reference, int ndims, double *sincos,
            int nvalues, double step, double probe_in, double probe_out,
            double removal_distance, double volume_cutoff, int box_adjustment,
            double *P2, int nndims, int is_ses, int nthreads, int verbose)
{
```

What am I missing about the different number of arguments and their different order ? How can Python get the correct results with such differences ? I think Python C bindings are provided by SWIG. I should stress out that I don't know C at all , but was just trying to figure out what was going on under the hood of the really nice tool.

Comment: A function with two dozen parameters is anything but nice.

Comment: You could try using `ctypes`.

Comment: Swig can be configured to translate a Python list of integers , e.g., `[1,2,3]` to multiple C parameters such as `int *PI, int size`.  This is likely the reason for missing parameters

Comment: like `%apply (int* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* PI, int size)}`  in `pyKVFinder.i `  ? How should it be read (mean what does it do ?)?

Comment: The `%apply (int* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* PI, int size)}` means that `int* PI, int size` will be matched to the previously defined typemap suite for `(DATA_TYPE* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, DIM_TYPE DIM1)` https://github.com/LBC-LNBio/pyKVFinder/blob/master/C/numpy.i#L1997

Comment: Code with a lot of parameters usually wants to have a single structure (or two)  passed with all those variables as struct members.  Generally, when my function's params keep growing I resort to a structure so I don't have to update multiple places with each param add... ie: the definition, the declaration, all the called places, etc...

Comment: @Kz2023 this is commonly called a "parameter object."

Comment: See the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html).